# How can I model a flutted glass lamp's shade?

Tags: modeling, glass

I'm struggling with this decorated glass...

[image: lamp_shade]

I've tried with displacement, but it doesn't give me the desired look.

Answer (score 9):

Create this segment, mirror it:

[image]

Array it on X and Z:

[image]

Make it circular with a *Simple Deform* modifier, *Bend* mode, on Z:

[image]

Deform it with a *Lattice* modifier:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: wow! True mastercraft :) Thanks a lot, I'll try. Best!

Comment: You're welcome................   ;)